# How to make Linear Layout Background Transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve a scroll feature with a semi-circle I'm unable to reach this I want to make that linear layout transparent and just the image view to be visible. The problem here is it the edges of the linear layout which makes the feature fail.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@null">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_background" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"




        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please avoid creating 2 duplicate questions. You've just asked same 5 minutes ago

Comment: Your problem that the ScrollView is beginning right where the LinearLayout (@+id/linear) is ending; therefore there is nothing underneath the LinearLayout to show anyway. You need to use a different ViewGroup that permits Views stacking on top of each other like RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. Also make sure the green rounded rect resources has its corners transparent

Comment: @MarcEstrada I posted it again because the last post was not well written I know I had to edit it but I lost conviction sorry for duplicating it won't happen again.

Comment: @DuricanRadu The fix was Framelayout for me I just want to know why my scrollview is not scrolling to the full height of my linear layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FrameLayout` and add these two layouts in it. in FrameLayout, whichever element is last added will be on top of others.

SO here, add topper layout first in FrameLayout and then add ScrollView Layout which contains Avatar image.

That way, avatar image will be on top of topbar layout

```
<FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout> //topbar
    <LinearLayout> //ScrollView containing avatar and other stuff

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It really helped me thanks a lot. The scroll view is not scrolling the entire length of the linear layout any fix?

Comment: @Mr.Imposter do you need the topbarr to be scrolled as well? let me know updated xml..

Comment: No, we were trying to achieve a static toolbar feel and rest of the things to be scrolled below. This Framelayout view overlapping helped me achieve that successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this on your `LinearLayout`:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: seems not working

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but if you stumbled on this post then add this to your style.xml

```
<style name="ProgressDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then use it programmatically like this, assuming your progress dialog is in a linear layout

```
dialog = Dialog(this, R.style.ProgressDialogTheme)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress)
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
```