# how to make transparent layout with background image in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451144/how-to-make-linear-layout-background-transparent) but I am not getting proper solution over there?. Anyone here who can get me  out from this problem. I want to achieve scrolling content below the toolbar. I've added image in the background of  top layout but when I scroll the content white color over  the content comes out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm6nX.jpg)

```
<FrameLayout
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/def"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searchbar_design"
        android:layout_weight="3.9"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search1" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbar_design"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColorHint="@color/appColor"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ic_crown"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@drawable/crown" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="135sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80sp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_picture"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/anglena"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_nameprofile"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:text="Angilena Steven"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/btn_edit_profile"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_nameprofile"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/profile_edit" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout> 
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please from your question its not completely clear what you want.

Comment: @oziomajnr thanks for commenting let me edit it again

Comment: From your ss, it seems that some word is getting cut in half! What is the iaaue here and what u want as result?

Comment: i want to remove that cutting area so that bottom words shows up even when content reach below that  picture by scrolling.